# How to get same element value from xml which having same and different nodes using linq in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

**As shown in xml file  element has same and different node , in same  element  A and B are default for each  how can i get all node child nodes value based on on respective element**

is it possible to create a separate method for it and then check based on the type and then get the child node values?

**Xml File :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <File>
      <Record>
        <Data>
          <Type>A</Type>
          <office>
            <Road>
              <code> plot 309</code>
            </Road>
          </office>
          <Area>
            <AreaId>Pune</AreaId>
          </Area>
        </Data>
        <Data>
          <Type>B</Type>
          <office>
            <Road>
              <code> plot 309</code>
            </Road>
          </office>
          <Area>
            <AreaId>A50</AreaId>
            <AreaName>Pune</AreaName>
            <AreaDetails>Pune India</AreaDetails>
          </Area>
        </Data>
      </Record>
      <Record>
        <Data>
          <Type>A</Type>
          <office>
            <Road>
              <code> plot 400</code>
            </Road>
          </office>
          <Area>
            <AreaId>Mumbai</AreaId>
          </Area>
        </Data>
        <Data>
          <Type>B</Type>
          <office>
            <Road>
              <code> plot 400</code>
            </Road>
          </office>
          <Area>
            <AreaId>A70</AreaId>
            <AreaName>Mumbai</AreaName>
            <AreaDetails>Mumbai-India</AreaDetails>
          </Area>
        </Data>
      </Record>
    </File>
```

**C# code:**

```
XDocument xdocTest = XDocument.Load(@"E:xml\XMLFile1.xml");
var testRecords = (from root in xdocTest.Descendants("File")
               from Record in root.Elements("Record")
               select new
               {
                   typeA = (Record.Elements("Data").Elements("Type").Any() ==true) ? Record.Element("Data").Element("Type").Value: string.Empty,
                   typeB = (Record.Elements("Data").Elements("Type").Any() == true) ? Record.Element("Data").Element("Type").Value : string.Empty
                // Remaining child node 
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Is it good to use like this :                                                                              typeA = (Record.Elements("Data").First().Elements("Type").Any() ==true) ? Record.Elements("Data").First().Element("Type").Value: string.Empty,
                                   typeB = (Record.Elements("Data").Last().Elements("Type").Any() == true) ? Record.Elements("Data").Last().Element("Type").Value : string.Empty

Answer (score 0):

This code will return you List of "Record" with it's respective "A" and "B" type elements:

```
var testRecords = (from root in xdocTest.Descendants("File")
                    from Record in root.Elements("Record")
                    select new
                    {
                        typeA = (Record.Elements("Data").Elements("Type").Any() == true) ? Record.Elements("Data").Where(x=> x.Element("Type").Value=="A").ToList(): new List<XElement>(),
                        typeB = (Record.Elements("Data").Elements("Type").Any() == true) ? Record.Elements("Data").Where(x => x.Element("Type").Value == "B").ToList() : new List<XElement>()
                        // Remaining child node 
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: i want value like this : typeA = 'A' and typeB = 'B' and code for type A as codeA = 'plot 309' and code type for B as codeB = 'plot 309' so at the last i will get list of all  node so i can directly use that (note : like this i can get  remaining node )

Comment: @yashfale why don't you create class for Data and just deserializa xml?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Dictionary :

```
            XDocument xdocTest = XDocument.Load(@"E:xml\XMLFile1.xml");
            var testRecords = xdocTest.Descendants("Record").Select(x => new Dictionary<string, XElement>(
                x.Elements("Data").GroupBy(y => (string)y.Element("Type"), z => z)
                    .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault())
            ).ToList());
```